# AmCharts font-size in ems

Tags: font-size, amcharts

I'm rendering AmCharts on a responsive designed page.

Is it possible to set the font-size of the chart in ems instead of pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AmCharts doesn't support setting font size in ems.

Comment: This not answer for question